# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar la consulta de una categoría, excluyendo posts pertenecientes a otra, con la API REST de WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Estoy usando la REST API de WordPress para mostrar algunos posts desde otro sitio en mi frontend, cada posts debe pertenecer a una categoría diferente. Pero tengo una categoría de "Eventos destacados", en la que aparecen posts que ya se mostraron en otra categoría, de modo que tengo uno o a veces más posts "repetido" en dos categorías.

Mi consulta para la categoría destacada es así:

```
http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/events/?categories=23&per_page=1
```

Y quiero excluir los posts de esa categoría (porque ya se mostró en "Destacados"), para que no se muestren en otras áreas. Ya intenté estas consultas:

```
http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/events/?categories=42&per_page=1&filter[category__not_in]=23

// pero leyendo que category__not_in espera un array y no un escalar:
// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters
// Intenté esto, pasando el id de la categoría excluida como primer miembro del array:

http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/events/?categories=42&per_page=1&filter[category__not_in][]=23
```

Ya investigué en el sitio de WordPress, y hay una sugerencia, no relacionada con los parámetros a la API REST, sino acerca de los argumentos dados a WP_Query directament: [incluir posts en una categoría, pero excluir los que están en otra categoría también](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58948/16301). Ambas parecen funcionar [primero obteniendo todos los IDs de los posts que pertenecen a la categoría a ser excluida, y luego pasando ese array de IDs mediante el parámetro `exclude` a WP_Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69431/16301); lo que supongo que como consulta por HTTP quedaría así:

```
    http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/events/?categories=42&per_page=1&exclude[]=1&exclude[]=2&exclude[]=3
```

Sin embargo esto carga mucho el backend, pues se realizarían dos consultas. Y es más ineficiente aún en el frontend, ya que serían dos consultas por HTTP, primero para obtener los IDs a excluir, y luego para consultar posts en una categoría, pero que no sean esos IDs.

¿Hay una mejor forma de lograr esto? ¿No soporta WP_Query dos diferentes argumentos de categorías en la misma consulta? Cuando filtro por categorías, y etiquetas (en la misma consulta), no hay conflicto alguno.